# How to print variable above the while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to access `php variable` out of `while loop`. This `variable` has to be printed **above the while loop**. Following trick doesn't work

```
<?php
  $title = '';    
?>
<a href=""><?php echo $title?></a>
<?php
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM notice WHERE id=:id");
    $query->bindParam(':id',$_GET['id']);
    $query->execute();
        while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $title .= $row['title'];
?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: You need to execute the query-fetch operations first.

Comment: Put the line where you echo the title _below_ the loop.

Comment: @TiiJ7, below the loop will work. As asked in question, I have to echo this variable above the loop.

Comment: @Mureinik, how to echo `$title` variable above the `while loop`.

Comment: Why do you need the echo above the loop? A while loop produces no output in itself. It does not make a difference to put the echo below the loop.

Comment: @TiiJ7 you are correct, but after the `while loop` `$title` will be printed `more times` according to `rows count` in database. I want to echo `$title` only one time. For example title will be `News`, it  will be printed only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP always runs from top to bottom, so you cannot `echo` a variable before you fill it with a value.

So in this case you can solve your problem by placing the `echo` below the loop (that is, below the *end* of the loop).

```
<?php
  $title = '';    
  $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM notice WHERE id=:id");
  $query->bindParam(':id',$_GET['id']);
  $query->execute();
  while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $title .= $row['title'];
      // ....
  }
?>
<a href=""><?php echo $title?></a>
```

Should the loop itself also produce output and you want to put the title above this output, you will need to [buffer the output](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) of the loop until you are ready to send it.

```
<?php
  $title = '';    
  $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM notice WHERE id=:id");
  $query->bindParam(':id',$_GET['id']);
  $query->execute();
  ob_start();
  while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $title .= $row['title'];
       // Produce any output you want
  }
  $loop_output = ob_get_clean();
?>
<a href=""><?php echo $title ?></a>
<?php echo $loop_output ?>
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the code. how do i print the `$title` based on the `WHERE` clause. I do not want to loop all.